# 2010 Column Validation Formula

Tags: 2010, column, validation

This formula works fine when adding a new list item:

=[Class Date]>=TODAY()+3

Basically ensuring the user selects a date greater than two days away from current date.

I don't want the formula to be in effect if the record is an UPDATE to an existing record.

So if someone comes back to this record after completing it correctly and saving it, but now wants to update a different field I don't want this field to be editable nor do I want the validation formula to be applied to the updating of the record.

Is this possible?

Comment: If the field is not updateable, then would the validation formula even matter on update?

Answer (score 6):

Try the formular:

```
=OR([Class date]>=TODAY()+3,Created<TODAY())
```

Where the first formular could be specified as validation on the column, this needs to be at the list level:
[image]

Comment: I get this message with that: The formula cannot refer to another column.  Check the formula for spelling mistakes or change the column to this column.

Comment: modified answer to specify that validation must be moved to list level

Comment: This is the value of Created for one of the records in the list: Created at 4/6/2012 3:19 PM     AND this is the value of [Class Date] for that same record:  4/2/2012     SO, could it be the difference in format that is causing this issue?  I don't understand the error msg which I posted previously...appreciate the assistance!!

Comment: Did you see the comment about moving the formular from the column to the list?

Comment: That worked!!!  Thank you so much!!!  Wish I can return the favor some time....Joe