# How do you validate a column only if it's new item being added?

Tags: list, column, validation

I recently added validation to a field which works great.

```
=[Arrival Date]>=TODAY()-5
```

However, I ran into an issue when an employee is editing an older item to update the "Status" but it's not letting him save because it has an "Arrival Date" of like 3 months ago.

What I would like to do is validate ONLY new items because we want to only enter items within 5 days of arrival, otherwise we don't accept them.

I thought formula below would work because new items don't have an ID yet, but it doesn't seem to like it:

```
=IF([ID]="", [Arrival Date]>=TODAY()-5, [Arrival Data])
```

I have a feeling that there is a better concept out there, either way your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: are you doing list validation or field validation? becuase if you use field validation then it will only check the values enter into the that column as compare to list validation will validate everytime item update

Comment: I would need field validation, however, I would love to see what a solution would look like for both types.

Comment: EDIT: Ultimately I just want to validate new items, which seems like I should use list validation instead

Comment: Found a solution: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/36891/2010-column-validation-formula